# Putting div content out of browser window in electron app

Tags: html, angularjs, cross-platform, electron, desktop-application

I just cloned electron quickstart app from github. I see that it creates a browser window inside which we can put all our html content.

> mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

Something like this which creates a browser kind of window.But I am trying to make an app similar to sticky note where I want my div to stick directly on to desktop without any browser window.
Is it possible to do this with electron? If not what are the alternatives to make my app developed with angular to a desktop application.
I am a newbie to all of this. Kindly help

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Electron Frameless Window](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#create-a-frameless-window)

You can use it to "hide/disable" the window controls. You can also set the option "alwaysOnTop" in your browser window object so the application always stays on top of other applications. Search for the option on this page [Electron API Browser Window](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)

Comment: Thank you.But this will still have a window right? What i want instead is that I have a div which looks like a sticky note,I want that div to directly be present on the desktop without any window.

Comment: I confirm the response, frameless windows is what you need :)

Comment: so does that mean for every div i have to create a frame less window?For the purpose of clarity lets think for every sticky note i have to create a new frameless window?

Comment: No, the frameless window has no border at all and yes you would need a browser window instance for every div. Look at this image for example: https://jaanus.com/images/electron_frameless.png